# Is a zero initialized std::atomic<T*> guaranteed equivalent to one initialized with nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Given `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <atomic>

namespace {
    std::atomic<int*> gets_zero_init;
    std::atomic<int*> gets_nullptr{nullptr};
}
```

I'm confident that `gets_zero_init` is zero-initialized, and that its initialization is complete after zero-initialization. I'm also confident that `gets_nullptr` will ultimately be initialized with `nullptr`, I'm also fairly confident that `gets_nullptr`'s initialization isn't complete after zero-initialization, because `std::is_trivially_constructible<decltype(gets_nullptr), int*>::value` is `false` (at least, it is on my compiler). I'm however a little unclear on whether `gets_nullptr` is fully initialized after constant init, static init, or dynamic init. Which is it?

Furthermore, lets say, for the sake of argument, that I'm interested in ensuring that the object of interest is fully initialized after zero-initialization and does not require any further initialization, so I go with the `gets_zero_init` approach. The pointer embedded in `gets_zero_init` will hold the all-zeros bit-pattern due to zero-initialization.

Is it guaranteed that the all-zeros bit pattern is equivalent to `nullptr`? In other words, if I want the semantics of `gets_nullptr`, can I rely on the zero-initialization of `gets_zero_init` to provide that?

Comment: Tried `std::is_trivially_constructible<decltype(gets_nullptr), std::nullptr_t>::value`?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I actually tried that first. Just double checked, same issue. Compiler is `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)`, using libc++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

First, there is an error in my post. I had not realized that zero-init and constant-init were just different forms of static init. You get one or the other, not one then the other. So, ignore that bit of misunderstanding.

Both `gets_zero_init` and `gets_nullptr` get static initialization, I believe. The first gets zero initialization, sort of obviously. The second gets constant initialization because:

- The std::atomic constructor taking a T is constexpr
- The argument to the constructor of `gets_nullptr` is a constant expression

In other words, both `gets_zero_init` and `gets_nullptr` have static initialization, and therefore the latter one is the better choice, since it doesn't rely on assuming the all-zero bit pattern to be equivalent to nullptr.